# $http and $stateParams in resolve of $stateProvider, Unknown provider error

Tags: angularjs

The goal here is to send an http request with the same parameter of the state parameter. This will then display the food types associated with the cuisine type that has been clicked. Is this even theoretically possible?

```
"Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: getFoodsProvider <- getFoods <- AppCtrl"
```

**js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url:'/',
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
            controller: 'AppCtrl'
        })
        .state('food', {
            url: '/food/:cuisine',
            templateUrl: 'partials/food.html',
            controller: 'AppCtrl',
            resolve: {
                getFoods: ['$http', '$stateParams', function($http, $stateParams) {
                    var url = '/getfoods/' + $stateParams.cuisine;
                    return $http.get(url).success(function(response) {
                        return response.data;
                    })
                }]
            }
        });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});

myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', 'getFoods', function ($scope, getFoods) {
    $scope.foods= getFoods;
}]);
```

**home**

```
<md-list>
    <md-list-item ng-repeat="cuisine in cuisines">
        <a ui-sref="food({cuisine:cuisine})">{{cuisine}}</a>
    </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

**food**

```
<md-list>
    <md-list-item ng-repeat="food in foods">
        <div>{{food}}</div>
    </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

Comment: why you are not writing your whole business logic in your controller. ?

Comment: If possible I'd like to do it this way because, as far as I can tell, it's potentially cleaner and I'd like to try to keep business logic out of my controller as much as possible.

Comment: Then try with `$q` may be it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the off-chance that someone needs a solution to the same problem, you should know it was resolved by creating a separate controller for the state with the service (see comment below). The main controller was trying to load the 'getFoods' service when its associated state hadn't been activated yet. No promises necessary. Also, I added .data after the service in the controller.

**new controller**

```
var myApp= angular.module('myApp');

myApp.controller('foodCtrl', ['$scope', 'getFoods', function ($scope, getFoods) {

    $scope.foods = getFoods.data; //added .data after service

}]);
```

**main js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url:'/',
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
            controller: 'AppCtrl'
        })
        .state('food', {
            url: '/food/:cuisine',
            templateUrl: 'partials/food.html',
            controller: 'foodCtrl', //specify different controller
            resolve: {
                getFoods: ['$http', '$stateParams', function($http, $stateParams) {
                    var url = '/getfoods/' + $stateParams.cuisine;
                    return $http.get(url).success(function(response) {
                        return response.data;
                    })
                }]
            }
        });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems perfect and it should work. But I think as you're sending ajax request in the resolve and it works asynchronously you need a resolve there. And no need to use the resolve value in controller. Just set the data of the http response in a factory and use the same factory to get the data in the controller.

So try this:

```
resolve: {
            getFoods: ['$http', '$stateParams','$q','foodData' function($http, $stateParams, $q,foodData) {
                var url = '/getfoods/' + $stateParams.cuisine,
                 deferred = $q.defer(),
                $http.get(url).success(function(response) {
                    foodData.setData(response.data);
                    deferred.resolve();
                }).error(function(error){
                    deferred.reject();
                    $state.go(some other state);
                })
                return deferred.promise;
            }]
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same error with this approach.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're still getting the issue. It worked for me in few of my code. As the code is not working try it with a factory. Check my updated answer.